# I just updated my SSL certificate and now my site looses formatting when

Tags: ssl

Ever Since I update my SSL certificate, my site will not open properly unless I do not "not secure" the connection. If secured, the page looses all formatting. I believe my SSL is not properly setup. Is this true? Please help!

[image]
[image]

Comment: How are you loading your css? It is likely that css/js is using `http` instead of `https`

Comment: Oh ok. How would you go about fixing this issue? would you need to go into each individual file?

Comment: How are you loading your css?

Comment: Also, is the url in your site options set to http or https?

Comment: This link will scan your site for non https requests: [https://www.jitbit.com/sslcheck/](https://www.jitbit.com/sslcheck/). It has saved me a lot of time, especially when resources are loaded via JavaScipt or `@import` and can't be seen in the HTML source.

Comment: Maybe [this link](https://managewp.com/wordpress-ssl-settings-and-how-to-resolve-mixed-content-warnings) will help you a little to solve issues. A quote from a comment somewhere else *This type of CSS "breaking" is caused mostly due to accessing files via HTTP request on an HTTPS connection, or to be short, accessing insecure files.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also add some rules to your .htaccess file to rewrite all http:// URLs to https://

[This article from CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/moving-to-https-on-wordpress/) explains what else you can do to move a WordPress site completely to https://

Answer (score 0):

Many of the files you are including on your page are being called using http rather than https. It is likely that this is causing your problem.

If you want to test this before changing all your code, try copying the source code from your home page into a blank HTML file that you create in your root folder (e.g. test.html). Next, go through the HTML code for test.php and change every reference to http:// to https:// and save.

Load the file using https in your browser.

```
https://www.golocalexpert.com/test.php
```

If this is the problem, then this page should load properly. Now all you have to do is change your website code to render the page this way.